# Running cytospace.js 'cose' layout in node js

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is it possible to run a layout like 'cose' in node.js? I ran the layout. It is not complaining but x and y is always 0. Is there a way to supply width and height to the layout so that it could work in headless mode?

I am doing this just pre-calculate node positions for large network like 10000 nodes and 25000 links and then send to the client for just rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force-directed / physics simulation layouts usually don't work well if you don't specify unique initial node positions.  CoSE uses the existing positions by default.  If you leave all nodes at (0, 0) at init, you won't get any results.  Either specify manual positions to start or specify the randomisation option for CoSE so it sets initial positions itself.

Generally, layouts work fine headlessly.  You lose out on some things like overlap detection, because rendered dimensions can only be calculated by the renderer.  You can set the style enabled at init to get some basic width/height etc. taken into account by layouts -- but you won't get fancier renderer-only values like label overlap.  Just make sure to space out your nodes a bit more using the layout options.

Comment: Sorry for very late reply of appreciation. Thanks for your explanation. It helped